# "A pun of X" or "a pun based upon X"?

Tags: prepositions

In the following phrase, I am unsure of my usage of the word "of".

> The protocol name µDP (pronounced *mew-dee-pee*) is a pun of *mu*lticast *UDP*.

Is it said that something is a pun *of* something else, or is it perhaps instead the case that a pun is *based upon* something else?

Comment: _A pun on._ But what's the pun here?

Comment: Thank you.  Unless I'm misunderstanding the meaning of 'pun', the pun would be the use of "µ" as a stand in for "mU" in "mUDP" (itself an acronym of "multicast user datagram protocol").  There's a second level of wordplay by which the "µ" prefix designates "micro".  In the context of the main document, the smallness of µDP is very much at the forefront.  Does that qualify as a pun, or am I using the word incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting comments aside, the answer to your question as to how to mark the relationship between the pun and the punned seems to be clearly "pun on". [Here is an ngram analysis](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pun%20on%2C%20pun%20of%2C%20pun%20based%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpun%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpun%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpun%20based%20on%3B%2Cc0) comparing the usage of "pun of", "pun on" and "pun based on" and "pun on" is the clearly dominant phraseology.

[image]
So:

> µDP is a pun on UDP.

Of course any of the three would be readily understood, but I think this analysis clearly shows the idiom.

And, as my dear departed father used to say, jokes based on one word sounding like another are very punny indeed.